# How do I fix the pending promise in this case?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

The code works as expected:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
async function showArray(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    await showElement(arr[i]);
  }
}
async function showElement(x){
  console.log(x);
  document.getElementById('result').value+=x.toString();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("");
    }, 1000);
  });
}
(async()=>{ await showArray(a)})();
```

```html
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

When I enter the code into my console directly, it says:

[image]

There is a `Promise <pending>`, indicating there is a unresolved promise.

Is this a problem that I need to fix and how can I fix this?

Comment: Not a problem, it just means that your async function (which is immediately invoked) returns a Promise... as expected

Comment: also  can use promise.all

Comment: `var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

function showArray(arr){
  return arr.map(() => showElement());
}
function showElement(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

(async () => console.log(await Promise.all(showArray(a))))()`